# Strategies for Mapping Views in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, view

It seems that NHibernate needs to have an id tag specified as part of the mapping.  This presents a problem for views as most of the time (in my experience) a view will not have an Id.  I have mapped views before in nhibernate, but they way I did it seemed to be be messy to me.

Here is a **contrived** example of how I am doing it currently.

**Mapping**

```
  <class name="ProductView" table="viewProduct" mutable="false" >
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" >
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
<!-- more properties -->
  </class>
```

**View SQL**

```
Select NewID() as Id, ProductName as Name, --More columns
From Product
```

**Class**

```
public class ProductView
{
    public virtual Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Name {get; set;}
}
```

I don't need an Id for the product or in the case of some views I may not have an id for the view, depending on if I have control over the View

Is there a better way of mapping views to objects in nhibernate?

**Edit**
**Answer So Far**

**Mapping**

```
  <class name="ProductView" table="viewProduct" mutable="false" >
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" />
    <property name="Name" />
    <!-- more properties -->
  </class>
```

**Class**

```
 public class ProductView
    {
        public virtual Name {get; set;}
        //more properties
    }
```

**View SQL**
Do I still need NewID()?

```
Select NewID() as Id, ProductName as Name, --More columns
From Product
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it just a little bit cleaner by not mapping the Id to a property and omitting the generator:

```
<id column="Id" type="guid"/>
```

That way, you keep the problem in the data layer, without leaking the implementation detail to your domain.

Comment: does that mean that I can remove the NewID() from the TSQL Select as it is only there to satisfy nhibernate's need to an ID

Comment: No, that means your class doesn't need an Id property.

Comment: Ben's right. NHibernate does not need the Id to be mapped to a property, but it always needs a way to identify persistent instances.

Comment: thanks Diego, Ben.  Ok let see if I understand correctly. I need to include the id tag in the mapping, I dont need an Id property in my class.  Do I then need the need the newid() as part of sql or can that be droped as well and nhibernate will assign a guid to it?

Comment: You still need the newid(); NHibernate can only assign Ids on save, not make them up on load.

Comment: Thanks Diego, I don't want nhibernate to save if it is a view.  I only want it load.  and if I have to explicitly include a newID() in the TSQL to get around this then so be it. unless there is another way that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, NHibernate will require either an id or a [composite-id](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid) definition since it's the mechanism by which it uniquely identifies a given record.  If there is no combination of columns that provides a key for each row in the view, I think you are stuck with hacky workarounds.

Comment: I wish that when you mark a class as `mutable=false` that the explicit need for an Id goes away.  not sure if that is practical but would make scenarios like this easier to handle, imo.